# Make random subset of white pixels black in pygame surface

Tags: python, pygame

I have a pygame surface (some text created by font.render) that is mostly transparent except some pixels are white. I'd like to change half of these white pixels black. I know I could iterate through each pixel, checking whether it is white by get_at() and changing its color using set_at(), but it strikes me that there must be a faster way of telling pygame to grab all the white pixels and change a random half of them to black. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to iterate through all the pixels to check if they're white.  Once you have the list of whites, do something like:

```
for px in random.sample(whites,len(whites)/2):
    Surface.set_at((px.x,px.y),'black')
```

[Python Documentation - random](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html)